# Apache camel and <groovy> </groovy>

Tags: groovy, apache-camel, transform

I want to modify file with groovy using:

```
 <from uri="file:/data/inbox?delete=true" />
    <transform>
    <groovy>
        body =  body[1..3]
    </groovy>
    </transform>
<to uri="file:/data/outbox"/>
```

I get an error:

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
>   org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFile.getAt() is applicable for
>   argument types: (groovy.lang.IntRange) values: [1..3]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The body variable you receiving is a GenericFile which does not contain a getAt method. What are you trying to do?

Comment: What do you want to do with this `body =  body[1..3]` ?  In this case the original `body` is a `GenericFile` instance but the groovy script `body[1..3]` tries to invoke its `getAt()` method with an unsupported `IntRange` argument.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the input is file based and you attempt to use a groovy function that works on a list to grab the 1st to 3rd elements. You cannot do that. If you want to grab only the first 3 lines of a file, then you need to convert the message first to a list etc, or use the splitter eip to split the file line by line and group them together in a list which you can then afterwards do the groovy script